# Dual-OS boot from same UEFI partition with Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, multi-boot, uefi, grub2

There is a Windows 10 system (GPT) on a partition on a hard drive and a Ubuntu partition on the same drive, and of course an EFI system partition. During boot, Grub2 is used to choose either Windows or Ubuntu, but Windows is the default OS if nothing is selected within 1 second.

Right now I need to setup to run both Ubuntu and Windows concurrently, Windows is the host and Ubuntu as the guest.

Upon starting up the virtual machine which is set to use raw physical drive (the Ubuntu partition), the system loads the UEFI partition and again boots Windows 10 by default - this is a problem. I wish to set the EFI partition to load Ubuntu when it is loaded the second time.

The caveat is all of this need to be unattended (about <60 computers). Everytime when we start the classroom we need all the computers to start Windows as host and Ubuntu as the machine guest where the children will learn their multi-OS java demos.

How do I set the Grub2 in the EFI partition so that once Windows is loaded by default, the next default OS in Grub2 should be Linux? Is it possible to modify the grub.cfg in the EFI partition with a script to do something like this?

(we have used USB sticks before just for the EFI load but they tend to go missing and it has become too costly)

Comment: I am fairly certain that it is not possible to boot more than one system simultaneously using GRUB.   A better solution might be to use VMware player or VirtualBox.

Comment: What virtual machine (VM) software are you using? The solution is likely to depend upon the specific VM implementation you're using. You might need to set up a separate EFI System Partition (ESP) as a virtual disk or modify the VM's emulated NVRAM entries to launch GRUB before the Windows boot loader.

Comment: I am using VMware Workstation. Your two options are very interesting @RodSmith but I do not even know where to start on either of them.